# Can someone please explain why this is the first move when solving this integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral which I am solving is $$\int_0^c\sqrt{c^2-x^2}~\mathrm dx$$ and the first thing which they suggest doing is setting $x=(\sqrt{a})/(\sqrt{b}) \sin u$. I understand everything after this but I do not comprehend where and why this step came to be.

Comment: Do you mean $x = c \sin(u)$? I don't know why the author would suggest an amplitude $\sqrt{a}/\sqrt{b}$ when that doesn't appear in your integrand.

Comment: Modulo the comment by @Mattos, this is a standard trigonometric substitution.

Comment: In order to get rid of the ugly square root, and having in mind the idenitity $cos^2=1-sin^2$ you can make a substitution to first get rid of the $c^2$ and then a substitution to get rid of the square root  by means of the former identity. I guess that the substituion you intend to do, which is certainly not $x=\sqrt(a) / \sqrt{b}$ is the combination of both steps in one.

Comment: @Mattos That would be the general idea for $\int \sqrt{k-x^2}~\mathrm dx$ where $k$ is a positive rational number.

Comment: If the first step in the solution is $x=(\sqrt{a})/(\sqrt{b}) \sin u$, presumably at some later point they decide that $(\sqrt{a})/(\sqrt{b}) = c$. The _actual_ solution method (I think) is something like, "It looks like a sine substitution, so we should set $x$ equal to some constant times $\sin u$." One way to write a suitable constant is $(\sqrt{a})/(\sqrt{b})$, though it seems more confusing then useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is better to divide the procedure into two steps.

First by letting $X=x/c$ (here we assume $c>0$) we obtain
$$\int_0^c\sqrt{c^2-x^2}\,dx=c^2\int_0^1\sqrt{1-X^2}\,dX$$
Now it seems quite natural to use the substitution $X=\sin u$.

Comment: It's too short for an edit, but shouldn't it be $c$ instead of $c^2$ in front of the integral?

Comment: @Jared Goguen No, there are two factors $c$: one from the squareroot and one from $dx=cdX$

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate by geometry. $$ y = \sqrt{c^2-x^2}$$ is the top half of a circle of radius $c$ centered at the origin. Therefore the integral is a quarter of the area of a circle of radius $c$.

I.e. $\frac{1}{4}\pi c^2$.

Comment: Somehow, I find this is not a very satisfying answer for two reasons: 1. It is a standard exercise to "prove" that the area of such a circle is $\pi c^{2}$ using integrals ; 2. It does not help to master integral techniques, which seems to be the concern of the OP.
That said, it is always interesting to have other insight on a problem than the "standard" one. :)

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer I am teaching Calc 1 this semester, and we only cover very basic substitutions. That's why I went with this approach; it is what I would tell my students if it came up.

Comment: I get your point and as I said, this is an interesting approach. Yet, this is not very satisfying in my opinion (and if $x\mapsto c\sin x$ is not a basic substitution, I don't know what is). However, as you are a teacher, you probably know better than me what is appropriate or satisfying for a student.
In my country, we see this kind of substitution in high school, but it is considered much more difficult to understand that a circle can be decomposed as two (or four) functions.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Near the beginning of Calc 2, we have a section of the book that focuses on substitution using trig functions. That's why we wouldn't ask about something like this in Calc 1.

You make a good point. Personally I don't see this substitution as anything more than basic, but many calc students do.

Comment: I guess one's opinion on your answer highly depends on the way the education program is built in one's country. According to what you say, your answer seems coherent with "your" program, but not "mine". Interesting anyway, thanks!

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Of course! I am always interested to hear how math is taught in different places.

Comment: As I am! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

If you must do this by a method other than recognizing this as the area of one quarter of a circle, then the expression $\sqrt{c^2-x^2}$ suggests using the substitution
\begin{align}
x & = c\sin\theta \\
dx & = c\cos\theta\,d\theta \\[10pt]
\sqrt{c^2 -x^2} & = \sqrt{c^2 - c^2\sin^2\theta} = c\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta} \\[5pt]
& = c\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}  = c \cos\theta.
\end{align}
As $x$ goes from $0$ to $c$, then $\sin\theta$ goes from $0$ to $1$, so $\theta$ goes from  $0$ to $\pi/2$. So we get
$$
\int_0^c \sqrt{c^2-x^2}\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} c^2\cos^2\theta\,d\theta.
$$
One way of evaluating the integral is by using the trigonometric identity
$$
\cos^2\theta = \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 \cos(2\theta).
$$
There is also a way to do it without finding any antiderivatives: Observe that by symmetry, since $\cos\theta = \sin(\frac\pi2 - \theta)$, we have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2\theta\,d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta\,d\theta
$$
and then find the sum of those two integrals by using the identity $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$.